# WPAllImport custom php function to crop my data when importing it into custom fields

Tags: php, wordpress, customization

I have custom fields for the following in WPAllImport

1. `_yoast_wpseo_focuskw`
2. `_yoast_wpseo_title`
3. `_yoast_wpseo_metadesc`

For one and two I have used the field that is the product name. `{column_2[1]}`

For 3 I have used the field that contains the short description of the product. `{column_24[1]}`

For all of these fields I like to limit the number of characters used when importing. Is this possible please?

As an example `[my_custom_function({column_2[1]})]`

It is the my custom function part I am looking for which would limit the description of that field when it imports into WordPress.

Comment: substr( $str, $len );

Comment: @artisticPhoenix Sorry I do not understand.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php